# CreateView redirect with parameter created from the same view

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views, create-view

I have this CreateView that creates an object for me and after creating it I would like it to render me inside that object through its 'nome_scheda' which is a text field.

views.py

```
class SchedaCreateView(CreateView):
  model = Schede
  fields = ['nome_scheda','data_inizio','data_fine']
  template_name = 'crea/passo1.html'

  def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.utente = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

urls.py

```
path('crea/<nome>/', creazione, name="creazione_passo1"),
```

Comment: What is `nome`. Does your `Schede` model has a `nome`? Can you share the relevant (`Schede`) model?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the [**`.get_success_url(…)`** method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.FormMixin.get_success_url) to return the URL to redirect to by the browser:

```
class SchedaCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Schede
    fields = ['nome_scheda','data_inizio','data_fine']
    template_name = 'crea/passo1.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.utente = self.request.user
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('creazione_passo1', kwargs={ 'nome': self.object.nome })
```